# What does "x00000x0000x000x" signify in Verliog?

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I'm working on a Xilinx module, and during simulation one of my wires takes the value "x00000x0000x000x". What does this signify?

Comment: This was eventually resolved by realizing that we had redeclared a wire in our code. It's not clear why this signal was arising though.

Comment: declare one wire multiple time is similar to multi-driven. It can be simulated and some simulators may signify it in this way. If this code is synthesized, I expect a warning which telling the duplicated declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is that binary or hexadecimal value?

Basically it means you have a bus of wires, in which some bits are `X` (unknown), and others are `0`.

If I saw this binary value: `0x0x0x`, it would just mean that bits 5,3, and 1 are `0`, and bits 4,2, and 0 are `X`.

Comment: Just additional information. Probably depends on the simulator, but if the value is hex then x & X mean either one bit of the nibble is 'x' (e.g. '01x0') or all bits of the nibble are 'x' (e.g. 'xxxx')

Answer (score 2):

Basically this means two issues:

1. the wires signalling X may mean these wires or their drivers are not initialized properly. If they are not initialized yet by any practical data or they are not used in the design, this can be ignored. Otherwise, they should be fixed.
2. Multi-driven problem also cause X. If the x signalling is cause by wires have multiple drivers, these are errors and must be fixed.